# Looking for an adjective for an elected but not yet in charge person

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective for an elected but not yet in charge person.
I remember that there was a synonym for "soon to be" and "President-elect" but that's not the word I'm looking for. As far as I remember it started with `in[...]` and it could be used with `... president`.
I already did an extensive Google search and also here on StackExchange, but I can't find the appropriate word.

Comment: You're not looking for "incumbent" are you? That means "current" rather than "elected but not yet started".

Comment: Does _in waiting_ meet your requirements?

Comment: It would be the opposite of "incumbent" I guess. It's basically a president which is already elected but not yet incumbent. I read the word in an article back then when Obama was elected. I thought it sounded similar like incumbent and had at most 2 more syllables. It's sadly not `in waiting`, it was a single word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word I was looking for was `designate` ([Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/designate)), the `in...` was a mislead, sorry.

Comment: There is also the _adjectival_ form of the word [designate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/designate) which is pronounced with the emphasis on the first syllable in contrast to the verb which is usually pronounced with the emphasis more on the third syllable. This is placed after the title giving forms like "President designate" which is similar in meaning to "President elect"

Answer (score 3):

**[elect](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/elect)** (as an adjective)

1.2 postpositive Chosen for a position but not yet in office.
*‘The President-Elect’. ‘The special guest of honour for the evening was Patricia Metham, principal elect.’*